# sudo and chef-solo problems

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, sudo, chef, chef-solo

I'm facing a weird problem when executing chef-solo commands on Ubuntu 10.04.

If I execute this (as root):

```
# chef-solo -c /opt/mycorp/mycorp-chef-code/config/solo.rb -j /opt/mycorp/mycorp-chef-code/config/run_mycorp-config.json
[Tue, 16 Nov 2010 15:28:49 +0100] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[mycorp-config]"] from JSON
[Tue, 16 Nov 2010 15:28:49 +0100] INFO: Starting Chef Run (Version 0.9.12)
[Tue, 16 Nov 2010 15:28:49 +0100] INFO: Chef Run complete in 0.47172 seconds
[Tue, 16 Nov 2010 15:28:49 +0100] INFO: cleaning the checksum cache
[Tue, 16 Nov 2010 15:28:49 +0100] INFO: Running report handlers
[Tue, 16 Nov 2010 15:28:49 +0100] INFO: Report handlers complete
```

However If I execute the same exact command whith sudo (either as root or as a sudoer) I get this:

```
# sudo chef-solo -c /opt/mycorp/mycorp-chef-code/config/solo.rb -j /opt/mycorp/mycorp-chef-code/config/run_mycorp-config.json
[Tue, 16 Nov 2010 15:28:37 +0100] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[mycorp-config]"] from JSON
[Tue, 16 Nov 2010 15:28:37 +0100] INFO: Starting Chef Run (Version 0.9.12)
[Tue, 16 Nov 2010 15:28:38 +0100] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[Tue, 16 Nov 2010 15:28:38 +0100] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
/opt/mycorp/mycorp-chef-code/chef-repo/cookbooks/tomcat6/attributes/default.rb:45:in `from_file': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/../lib/chef/node.rb:578:in `load_attributes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/../lib/chef/node.rb:576:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/../lib/chef/node.rb:576:in `load_attributes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/../lib/chef/node.rb:575:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/../lib/chef/node.rb:575:in `load_attributes'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:74:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/../lib/chef/run_context.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:155:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/../lib/chef/client.rb:155:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:190:in `run_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:181:in `loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:181:in `run_application'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/../lib/chef/application.rb:62:in `run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.9.12/bin/chef-solo:25
    from /usr/bin/chef-solo:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/chef-solo:19
```

Any idea? I'm definitely lost on this, why would using sudo cause a problem, even if the user issuing the command is root.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Diving into "tomcat6" recipe showed that it needed java to work. It was not in the default PATH used by sudo and that was why it failed. Adding a customised "Defaults secure_path = "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/my_java/" to sudoers file did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit strange but Sudo does change environment variables so maybe chef-solo is thrown off by that.

As root run: `env`
and then run `sudo env`

You'll see that the variables are completely different.

#### Other toughts

Here is some info form the man page:

> If sudo is run by root and the SUDO_USER environment variable is set,
>          sudo will use this value to determine who the actual user is. 
>   This can
>          be used by a user to log commands through sudo even when a root
>   shell
>          has been invoked.  It also allows the -e flag to remain useful
>   even
>          when being run via a sudo-run script or program.  Note however, that
>          the sudoers lookup is still done for root, not the user specified
>   by
>          SUDO_USER.

Is your SUDO_USER set before you run sudo? Check with `echo $SUDO_USER`.

The sudoers table still gets consulted even if you are root so check your sudoers file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, it was related to $PATH variable being different inside the sudo environment.

Comment: The actual problem is that the default sudoers file in Ubuntu does "env_reset". Best bet is to use chef to replace the broken default configuration. Its not more secure :).